# looping through elements jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to select elements which contains id attribute and class attribute having 'child-of-' value and loop through the elements returned by the selector.

So far i could write:

```
$('.child-of-').each(function(){
...
});
```

This selects all the elements having class of child-of- including elements which does not have id also.
There are elements which has that class but does not have any id attribute.
 so How can i select elements which has 'id' attribute and id has some value and also has class of child-of-. ?

For example

```
 <div id="any1" class="child-of-"></div>
 <div id="any2" class="child-of-"></div>
 <div class="child-of-"></div>
```

Only the div having id attribute must be selected. ie the first two divs in the example. the third does not have id attribute value and hence should not be selected

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your question doesn't have any question marks.

Comment: Is `child-of-`  just part of the class name?

Comment: both havind child-of- as attreibute (ID and class)? or just having an ID AND a class 'child-of-'?

Comment: tx for asking a question now :-P

Comment: the element should have id attribute no matter what's its value is, but id attribute must exist with some value

Comment: there are elements which has that class but no id attribute in that element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `attribute selector`.

```
$('.child-of-[id]').each(function(){
    ...
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwZer/1/)

---

If your classes starts with `child-of-` you can use `attribute starts with` selector:

```
$('[class^="child-of-"][id]').each(function(){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[id].child-of-').each(function(){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this selector:

```
$('#child-of-.child-of-').each(function(){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the attribute values you would use the attribute selectors:

```
$('[id*="child-of-"][class*="child-of-"]').each(function...
```

Substring attribute selectors - http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/